# Golang: runtime.GC guarantees

Tags: collections, go, garbage-collection, runtime, garbage

Just wondering if there are any guarantees behind Go's `runtime.GC()` call.

Is it always true that if there are unreferenced objects, then `runtime.GC()` will free them and that free space will be reflected in subsequent calls to `runtime.ReadMemStats()`?

Comment: I don't think that's guaranteed. I would see `runtime.GC()` more as a hint to the runtime to run the garbage collector right now; it can decide on its own whether that makes sense right now. This function probably becomes obsolete anyway with the new concurrent garbage collector.

Comment: I am under the same impression, but I am wondering if there is a specification that can clarify the exact semantics the call should implement.

Comment: When in doubt, file an issue.